# Flask API for converting Contact Form responses to Email notifications (with reCAPTCHAv2)

Tags: python, form, email, flask, captcha

## Introduction

I wrote a proof-of-concept Flask server that accepts responses from a contact form and converts the data submitted to an email. I have added a rudimentary honeypot field that causes the form's response to discarded when the field is full. Additionally, I have integrated Google's reCAPTCHAv2 (intentionally over v3) to bolster the spam protection.

I have kept the dependency on third party modules to a minimum: I require only `flask` and `requests`. I do not think my use-case is complex enough to warrant the use of an abstraction in the form of a third-party reCAPTCHA library.

Additionally, this is just a test. When I deploy this, I want to keep my contact form on a static website and the form validation endpoint on a different domain.

## Overview

The flask server exposes two endpoints:

1. GET at `/` - the home page that contains the sample contact form. The full HTML content is in `main.html`. Note that I plan to keep this form in a static website on a different domain than the email notifier endpoint.
2. POST at `/contactform` - validates the form response and sends a notification to the configured email when a genuine request appears. Then conditionally renders a success template (see `accepted.html`)

These two endpoints are exposed in `main.py`, which depends on `send_mail.py` to send the email.

Additionally, it makes use of the following (secret) environment variables:

1. `SENDER_EMAIL` - The email address whose server we'll log into to send emails.
2. `PASSWORD` - The password for the email account.
3. `RECEIVER_EMAIL` - Since this is for converting a form response into a notification email, there is only one receiver. The code can be modified to notify several people.
4. `GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY` - The server side key that is used to validate reCAPTCHA responses.

## Source Code

### `main.py`

```py
import os
import json
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

from send_mail import send_mail

_BOT_IDENTIFIED = 'OK'

app = Flask(__name__)


def is_bot(captcha_response):
    secret = os.getenv('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY')
    payload = {'response': captcha_response, 'secret': secret}
    response = requests.post(
        "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", payload)
    response_text = json.loads(response.text)
    return not response_text['success']


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def hello_world():
    return render_template('main.html')


@app.route('/contactform', methods=["POST"])
def respond_to_formsubmit():
    trap = request.form['extrainfo']
    if trap.strip() != '':
        return _BOT_IDENTIFIED

    captcha = request.form['g-recaptcha-response']
    if is_bot(captcha_response=captcha):
        return _BOT_IDENTIFIED

    name = request.form['name']
    email = request.form['email']
    subject = request.form['subject']
    details = request.form['details']

    mail_info = {
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "subject": subject,
        "details": details,
    }

    send_mail(mail_info)

    return render_template('accepted.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

### `send_mail.py`

```py
import smtplib
import ssl
import os

from email.message import EmailMessage

_SMTP_SERVER_DOMAIN = 'smtp.gmail.com'
_SMTP_SERVER_PORT = 587


def retrieve_credentials():
    try:
        sender_email = os.getenv('SENDER_EMAIL')
        password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
        receiver_email = os.getenv('RECEIVER_EMAIL')
    except:
        print('Could not retrieve credentials. Make sure environment variables are initialized.')
        exit(1)
    return sender_email, password, receiver_email


def prepare_email(mail_info, sender_email, receiver_email):
    msg = EmailMessage()

    content = f'Name: {mail_info["name"]}\n' \
        f'Email: {mail_info["email"]}\n' \
        f'Subject: {mail_info["subject"]}\n\n' \
        f'Details:\n\n{mail_info["details"]}'

    msg.set_content(content)

    msg['Subject'] = f"Form input: {mail_info['subject']}"
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = receiver_email

    return msg


def send_mail(mail_info):
    sender_email, password, receiver_email = retrieve_credentials()

    msg = prepare_email(mail_info, sender_email, receiver_email)

    smtp_server = _SMTP_SERVER_DOMAIN
    port = _SMTP_SERVER_PORT

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.send_message(msg)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        server.quit()
```

### `templates/main.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
      #extrainfo {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>Sample Contact Form</h1>
      <p>
        This page has a simple contact form. I want to enter details into the
        form and then run a Deta Micro to convert the information entered to an
        email that is sent to my email address.
      </p>
      <form action="/contactform" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          id="name"
          placeholder="John Wick"
          required
        />

        <label for="email">Email </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="awesome@email.com"
          required
        />

        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required />

        <label for="details">Details</label>
        <textarea
          name="details"
          id="details"
          cols="40"
          rows="10"
          required
        ></textarea>

        <div class="required"><p>All fields are required.</p></div>

        <div
          class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey="--- YOUR SITE KEY GOES HERE ---"
          data-callback="tryToEnableButton"
          data-expired-callback="disableButton"
        ></div>

        <input type="text" name="extrainfo" id="extrainfo" />

        <button type="submit" id="submit-button" disabled>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
      function tryToEnableButton() {
        if (grecaptcha.getResponse().length > 0) {
          submitButton.disabled = false;
        }
      }
      function disableButton() {
        submitButton.disabled = true;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### `templates/accepted.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Form Submission</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <p>Your query has been submitted successfully!</p>
      <p>Please allow upto a week for a response.</p>
      <div class="main-button-container">
        <button class="main-button" onclick="window.history.go(-1)">
          Go Back
        </button>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

### `static/css/style.css`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #f3f1ef;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
main {
  padding: 1rem;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
main p {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
.required {
  color: #861212;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
form input,
form label,
form p {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
}
form input {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
form button,
.main-button {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #c52020;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.main-button-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
button:disabled {
  filter: grayscale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.9;
}
form textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
form textarea,
form input {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 50ch) {
  main {
    max-width: 40ch;
  }
}
```

## Specific Points

I am happy that the code works as intended, but since this will be deployed to the public, I can never be too sure. Hence, I will appreciate any non-blanketed, to-the-point technical advice. I am not an expert at Backend Development so I am willing to learn.

I appreciate comments on the general architecture of the code, any refactoring advice, or alternate implementation suggestions. Suggestions on DevOps are especially welcome.